# Understanding Screen Sizes/Pixel Density for Web Development (Websites & Emails)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email, meta-tags

I'm trying to understand a few things that deal with pixels.

The first of which is what changes between developing an html email and a website in terms of appearing on a mobile screen. To be more specific, when developing a website, I can have media queries that run below 375px (i.e. @medie screen and (max-width 375px)) and the changes occurring in that code will not be reflected on desktop (since most browsers without going into inspect restrict their width at 400px); however, on a phone that has a smaller screen like my iPhone SE, the changes that occur under this media query DO get hit.

So that on its own makes sense to me, because my phone screen is smaller than my min browser width, of course the changes I apply in that block will hit when the website is executed on my phone. But now is where some confusion gets introduced. When developing an HTML email, I have a table set to 600px wide. There is no media query affecting this HTML. The table is 600px wide under all circumstances, so when displaying on my less than 600px wide phone, I would assume that some of the page would clipped, but this is not so. When viewing the email in something like GMAIL, the entire composition is visible. This made me scratch my head for a bit, so I researched and found some sources claiming that this phone is actually greater than 600px wide. So my thought is that the screen density is just greater than that of my laptop, or maybe its some magic that GMAIL is applying, but either way, the email shows up just as it would on my laptop in a browser width greater than 600px.

I'm using these meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

and I have a base understanding of what they do, but how do these contribute to mobile exactly?

In summary, my main questions are as follows:

- why is it that my media queries with websites that run max-width: 375px hit my phone, and yet a table which is always 600px wide is fully viewable a the same time?
- is this a matter of screen pixel density, or is it a little more complex?
- what roles do these meta tags play exactly?

Any insight you can provide would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "the entire composition is visible." you mean it shows a scroll right?

Comment: No, I mean it resizes to the screen width as if the device was 600+ pixels wide.

Comment: "I have a table set to 600px wide." setting it literally `width="600"`?

Comment: Yes, literally width="600"

Answer (score 0):

> why is it that my media queries with websites that run max-width: `375px` hit my phone, and yet a table which is always `600px` wide is
>   fully viewable a the same time?

Because your phone visual port actually has a width of `1136` pixels and a height of `640` pixels.

> is this a matter of screen pixel density, or is it a little more complex?

Its a matter of screen pixel density, the default pixel ratio depends on the display density:

```
Default ratio when the viewport scale equals 1
Display density < 200dpi Ratio = 1.0
Display density > 200dpi && Display density < 300dpi Ratio = 1.5
Display density > 300dpi Ratio = integer floor(density/150dpi)
```

for the iPhone SE its 326 ppi (pixel per inch).

> what roles do these meta tags play exactly?

The tag its not part of any web standard and it was introduced by Mobile Safari, the width property controls the with size of the viewport, `device-width` its a special value, this is a typical use of the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

which sets the width to the width of the device viewport, and a zoom of 1, the width its in `CSS pixels` it doesnt take into account pixel density at all. Changing the value of the meta tag with JavaScript works, the website will react to the new value.
Try setting the width to 375px to see what happens in your phone.

Check this 2 articles:

- [pixel its not a pixel](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)
- [2 viewports](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)